# Parsing through a really long text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm a complete beginner to python, but I am making a web scraper as a project.
I'm using a jupyter notebook, beautifulsoup, and lxml.

I managed to grab the text that contains all the information I need, but now I'm lost on what to do.
I want to obtain specific pieces of data like longitude, latitude, siteid, direction (North, South, etc.), and I want to download the photos and rename them. I need to do this for all 41 locations.
If anyone could suggest any packages or methods I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Here's a small portion of the text I grabbed (pattern repeats 41 times):

```html
{
  "count": 41,
  "message": "success",
  "results": [
    {
      "protocol": "land_covers",
      "measuredDate": "2020-06-13",
      "createDate": "2020-06-13T16:35:04",
      "updateDate": "2020-06-15T14:00:10",
      "publishDate": "2020-07-17T21:06:31",
      "organizationId": 17043304,
      "organizationName": "United States of America Citizen Science",
      "siteId": 202689,
      "siteName": "18TWK294769",
      "countryName": null,
      "countryCode": null,
      "latitude": xx.xxx(edited),
      "longitude": xx.xxx(edited),
      "elevation": 25.4,
      "pid": 163672280,
      "data": {
        "landcoversDownwardPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682247/original.jpg",
        "landcoversEastExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -14.32171587255965))",
        "landcoversEastPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682242/original.jpg",
        "landcoversMucCode": null,
        "landcoversUpwardPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682246/original.jpg",
        "landcoversEastCaption": "",
        "landcoversMeasurementLatitude": xx.xxx(edited),
        "landcoversWestClassifications": null,
        "landcoversNorthCaption": "",
        "landcoversNorthExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -10.817734330181267))",
        "landcoversDataSource": "GLOBE Observer App",
        "landcoversDryGround": true,
        "landcoversSouthClassifications": null,
        "landcoversWestCaption": "",
        "landcoversNorthPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682241/original.jpg",
        "landcoversUpwardCaption": "",
        "landcoversDownwardExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -84.48900393488086))",
        "landcoversEastClassifications": null,
        "landcoversMucDetails": "",
        "landcoversMeasuredAt": "2020-06-13T15:12:00",
        "landcoversDownwardCaption": "",
        "landcoversSouthPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682243/original.jpg",
        "landcoversMuddy": false,
        "landcoversWestPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682245/original.jpg",
        "landcoversStandingWater": false,
        "landcoversLeavesOnTrees": true,
        "landcoversUserid": 67150810,
        "landcoversSouthExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -14.872806403121302))",
        "landcoversSouthCaption": "",
        "landcoversRainingSnowing": false,
        "landcoversUpwardExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: 89.09211989270894))",
        "landcoversMeasurementElevation": 24.1,
        "landcoversWestExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -15.47334477111039))",
        "landcoversLandCoverId": 32043,
        "landcoversMeasurementLongitude": xx.xxx(edited),
        "landcoversMucDescription": null,
        "landcoversSnowIce": false,
        "landcoversNorthClassifications": null,
        "landcoversFieldNotes": "(none)"
      }
    },
    {
      "protocol": "land_covers",
      "measuredDate": "2020-06-13",
      "createDate": "2020-06-13T16:35:04",
      "updateDate": "2020-06-15T14:00:10",
      "publishDate": "2020-07-17T21:06:31",
      "organizationId": 17043304,
      "organizationName": "United States of America Citizen Science",
      "siteId": 202689,
      "siteName": "18TWK294769",
      "countryName": null,
      "countryCode": null,
      "latitude": xx.xxx(edited),
      "longitude": xx.xxx(edited),
      "elevation": 25.4,
      "pid": 163672280,
      "data": {
        "landcoversDownwardPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682240/original.jpg",
        "landcoversEastExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -6.06710116543897))",
        "landcoversEastPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682235/original.jpg",
        "landcoversMucCode": null,
        "landcoversUpwardPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682239/original.jpg",
        "landcoversEastCaption": "",
        "landcoversMeasurementLatitude": xx.xxx(edited),
        "landcoversWestClassifications": null,
        "landcoversNorthCaption": "",
        "landcoversNorthExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -9.199031748908894))",
        "landcoversDataSource": "GLOBE Observer App",
        "landcoversDryGround": true,
        "landcoversSouthClassifications": null,
        "landcoversWestCaption": "",
        "landcoversNorthPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682233/original.jpg",
        "landcoversUpwardCaption": "",
        "landcoversDownwardExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -88.86569321651771))",
        "landcoversEastClassifications": null,
        "landcoversMucDetails": "",
        "landcoversMeasuredAt": "2020-06-13T15:07:00",
        "landcoversDownwardCaption": "",
        "landcoversSouthPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682236/original.jpg",
        "landcoversMuddy": false,
        "landcoversWestPhotoUrl": "https://data.globe.gov/system/photos/2020/06/13/1682237/original.jpg",
        "landcoversStandingWater": false,
        "landcoversLeavesOnTrees": true,
        "landcoversUserid": 67150810,
        "landcoversSouthExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -11.615041431350335))",
        "landcoversSouthCaption": "",
        "landcoversRainingSnowing": false,
        "landcoversUpwardExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: 86.6284079864236))",
        "landcoversMeasurementElevation": 24,
        "landcoversWestExtraData": "(source: app, (compassData.horizon: -9.251774266832626))",
        "landcoversLandCoverId": 32042,
        "landcoversMeasurementLongitude": xx.xxx(edited),
        "landcoversMucDescription": null,
        "landcoversSnowIce": false,
        "landcoversNorthClassifications": null,
        "landcoversFieldNotes": "(none)"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Looks like json. Python has a module of the same name to handle it.

Comment: or the `jq` cmd-line utility is very powerful for reformatting and extracting specific data. There are many Q/As here for it use and several power users that give great advice. Good luck with your project (however you tackle it!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see some code. Having said that, as has been pointed out, the built-in json library would help you. This is a JSON formatted output, please see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_json_intro.asp) for an introduction to this type of format.

Say for sake your output here is stored within a variable called `data`. You could convert this json data to a dictionary.

### Coding Example

```
import json
data_dict = json.load(data)
```

What json.load does is takes a JSON object and converts this into a python dictionary. The json.load actually scans the variable to check if it's a JSON object and uses a conversion table to convert this into a dictionary. There are other json formats that get converted to other python object types. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table) for that table.

Now you have a python dictionary which you can access the data from. So lets go through longitude, latitude, siteid, direction (North, South, etc.). I see there's an open '[' without the corresponding ']'. I can only assume that the list has 41 items in it from what you're describing, so I'll take the first result first. You can always loop through this quite easily to get all 41 results.

```
longitude = data_dict['results'][0]['longitude']
langitude = data_dict['results'][0]['langitude']
site_id = data_dict['results'][0]['siteid']
```

### Tips

1. I always use jupyter notebooks as a quick way to try and grab the specific data I want from JSON objects, sometimes it can take a few goes at getting the right access the right part. That way when I write my variables I know I get the data I want back from the JSON object. Json objects can be heavily nested sometimes and can be hard to follow.